# left-continuity / right-continuity of two processes with cycling definition.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Let's fix two processes, $\lambda$ and $N$.

$N$ is defined as a point process (with some fancy conditions that are not important here. It shall be right continuity as processes are usually. On the other hand, I define $\lambda$ in the following way:

$$ \lambda (t \mid \mathcal F_{t^-} ) = 
\int_0^t \mu( t - s ) d N_s $$

where $\mu$ is a continuous function. I am baffled because I noticed that

> If one knows that $N$ has jumps $(t_1, \cdots, t_n)$ on $[0,T]$, and
> that the process can be written as:

$$N(t) = \sum_{ \{ k : t_k \leq t
 \} } 1 $$

then:

$$ \int_{[0,T]} \mu(s) d N_s =\sum_{ \{ k
 : t_k \leq T \} }\mu(t_k)  $$

$1_A$ is the indicator/characteristic function over the set $A$.

however, $\lambda$ should be left continuous. It seems to me that by definition, the term $\sum_{ \{ k
 : t_k \leq T \} }\mu(t_k)  $ is right continuous.  It would become left continuous if inside the sum, the condition on the $k$'s was strictly lower than the bound.

**What am I missing please ?**

Comment: What is $1_{t-t_k}$?

Comment: @zhoraster it is the indicator function, $$1_A$$ is defined as $1$ on $A$ and $0$ everywhere else.

Comment: Ok. But you have $A = \{t-t_1\}$, which makes this illegible. There should be some inequality perhaps.

Comment: @zhoraster oh damn you're right! I corrected it. Does it make more sense now ? my mistake came from using indicator function instead of the heaviside function.

Comment: There are some new typos introduced, but at least it is clear. The process is right-continuous, since the indicators $1_{t\ge t_k} = 1_{[t_k,+\infty)}(t)$ are.

Comment: do you see other typos? sorry for that I tried my best to be clear and concise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110840/discussion-between-zhoraster-and-marine-galantin).

Answer (score 0):

My guess for now is that it depends on the notation of $dN_s$. Depending on its definition, one has different meaning of the stochastic integral, and thus either left or right continuity.